# simple query - issue with global variables

Tags: java, android, class, object

Simple query.
I set a variable in a method "BP". Now "this.dataType" has value "com.BP"
But now if I call another method getBP this variable is empty.

How to retain the value of "this.dataType"????

```
public void BP(String type) {
            this.dataType = type;   // here "this.dataType" is "com.BP"
        }


public getBP(){
            Log.i("data type:", this.dataType); 
            return this.dataType       //why is "this.datatype" empty
```

Comment: make sure you are calling getBP after BP

Comment: yup calling it after dataType is set. But I am setting it and calling it in different methods.